# file_exists weird behaviour when called from a browser

Tags: php, macos, apache

I have a weird behaviour with `file_exists()`:

When called from a browser:

- `file_exists()` will detect my desktop (on mac):  `/Users/myName/Desktop`
- `file_exists()` will NOT detect a file on my desktop: `/Users/myName/Desktop/any`

I have chmoded the any dir with 777

```
chmod -R 777 /Users/myName/Desktop/any
```

When called as a script (first line = `#!/usr/bin/env php`), both files are recognized.

Do you have a clue on this issue?

Is it apache related? (I have modified my default apache conf to get the smallest file possible, so I may have removed important directives as well) Or is it mac related?

Here is my script:

```
<?php

var_dump(file_exists("/Users/myName/Desktop"));         // true
var_dump(file_exists("/Users/myName/Desktop/dd"));      // false
```

Comment: Just for your understanding: not the ``browser`` is executing the functions but always the server or the be precise the php interpreter AT the server.

Comment: yes, right. That gives a clue why php shell script works, and that the problem is more apache related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTTP server may run on a specific user. Your desktop is protected to your account. On Mac OS, other users can't access to your desktop.

Result = your http server can't access to your desktop because it is running on another user :)

If you need your http server access some of your personal files, use your ~/public directory.

Comment: Thanks, that was it. I instead changed the apache user to my Os account, and the file_exists() worked as expected.